# Closing one form and opening another without visible changes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to close one form and open another without any visible changes (the new form should be open at the same place and user should not be able to see that there are 2 forms). This is how I imagined to do so far.
First, on button click I'm creating next form and in its constructor I'm sending 'this' of the current one:

```
private void TryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     InfoForm nextForm = new InfoForm(this);
     nextForm.Show();
}
```

In constructor of the next form I set visibility of previous form to false:

```
public InfoForm(MainForm prevForm)
{
     prevForm.Visible = false;
}
```

Can you tell me why this is not working? When I try to start my app for the second time, it says me that the process cannot access the file xxxx because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to show a second form which is identical to the first form? You are supposed to redefine how your first form works depending on the stage of your process. As simple as that. Not sure if you are aware, but you can have hidden controls, that can appear later in the workflow, there is no need to have a second form, unless it's a totally different second form. A better way of doing it is having multiple panels on the form, each having their own set of controls, you just show/hide panels. [Wizard style](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/dialogboxes/dlgboxes/mfcaw1.gif).

Comment: The second form IS totally different from the first form. You can see in the code that there is MainForm and InfoForm. How did you figure out that forms are the same?

Comment: You said `without visible changes`. If the second form is different, inevitably there will be visible changes to the user.

Comment: Without visible changes while transforming from one form to another.So what I meant is changes in the transformation ,not the look of the form

Comment: Ok, now you need to clarify what transformation is. Do you mean visual morphing of controls shapes to new form's controls? Blur from one form to another? A screenshot/video/mockup would help explain - feel free to attach to your question.

Comment: What I mean is to close first form and open another form on the same place on the screen. That two forms are already the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to do it. The next code creates next form which is InfoForm and in its constructor sends 'this' of the current form(type MainForm):

```
 private void TryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      InfoForm nextForm = new InfoForm(this);
      nextForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
      nextForm.ShowDialog(this);
 }
```

This is how constructor of the next form looks:

```
 public InfoForm(MainForm prevForm)
 {
      prevForm.Visible = false;
 }
```

The only thing you have to look for is to make these two forms to show on the exact same place on the screen. You can do this just by playing with properties of these two forms (e.g. you can put the form location to the center of the screen).

**EDIT**: I have added next code:

```
 nextForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

In this way nextForm appears in the center of the previous form which is MainForm.

Answer (score 1):

Try the same thing with [panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s. Instead of having two forms with different set of controls, have two panels on the same form. Or, if you prefer to keep code separate, create two new user controls, add both to your form, and hide/show depending on your need.